# geting the child attribute value using client side scripting

Tags: javascript, jquery, xslt, xpath

my xml file:

```
<childrens>
        <child1 entity_id = "1" value = "Asia">
              <child2 entity_id = "2" value = "India"></child2> 
              <child3 enity_id = "3" value = "China"></child3>
        </child1> 
</childrens>
```

this is my code:

```
<script>
     $(function() {
         $('#update-target a').click(function() {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 url: "try.xml",
                 dataType: "xml",
                 success: function(xml) {
                     $(xml).find('child1').each(function(){
                         var value_text = $(this).attr('value')
                         $('<li></li>')
                             .html(value_text)
                             .appendTo('#update-target ol');
                     }); //close each(
                 }
             }); //close $.ajax(
         }); //close click(
     }); //close $(
     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <p>
       <div id='update-target'>
         <a href="#">Click here to load value</a>
         <ol></ol>
       </div>
     </p>
```

I want to output if i have click asia than its display india and china 
using any of client side scripting language.

Comment: Is this code not working? what is the output you are getting?

Comment: @gurvinder372 i got the  output but i want something more on this can wait a minute i give u link

Comment: @gurvinder372 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458340/i-want-to-fetch-all-child-tab-sub-child-atrribute-value