# I want to fetch all child tab sub child atrribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xpath

This is my xml:

```
<root>
<child1 entity_id = "1" value= "Asia">
    <child2 entity_id = "2" value = "india">
        <child3 entity_id = "3" value = "Gujarat">
            <child5 entity_id = "5" value ="Rajkot"></child5>
        </child3>
        <child4 entity_id = "4" value = "Rajshthan">
            <child6 entity_id = "6" value = "Ajmer"></child6>
        </child4>
    </child2>
</child1>
</root>
```

This is my code:

```
<script>
    data = false;
    loaded = false;

    function loadChild(id) {
        if(!loaded) {
            ul = "<ul>";
            $(data).find("[entity_id='" + id + "']").children().each(function(){
                 var value_text = $(this).attr('value');
                 var id = $(this).attr('entity_id');

                ul += "<li id='" + id + "'>" + value_text + "</li>";
             });
             ul += "</ul>";
             $("#" + id).append(ul);
             loaded = true;
        }
    }

     $(function() {
         $('#update-target a').click(function() {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 url: "final.xml",
                 dataType: "xml",
                 success: function(xml) {
                    data = xml;
                    //console.log(data);
                     $(xml).find('child1').each(function(){
                         var value_text = $(this).attr('value');
                         var id = $(this).attr('entity_id');
                         $("<li id='" + id + "' onclick=\"loadChild('" + id + "');\"></li>")
                             .html(value_text)
                             .appendTo('#update-target ol');
                     }); //close each(
                 }
             }); //close $.ajax(
         }); //close click(
     }); //close $(
    </script>
```

this is my out-put :

```
 Click here to load value

    Asia
        india
```

But now I want:

- to click on india and then display `Gujarat` and `Rajshthan`.
- to click on `Gujarat` then display `Rajkot`.
- to click on `Rajshthan` then display `Ajmer`.